# QGis - Save and Layout menus are blank

Tags: qgis, linux, coordinate-system

I'm having a problem on QGIS 3.16.5,
mostly all sub-menus in Project menu, like Save, Save as, Layout Manager, they are blank and unusable.

Google search of this issue showed only other similar problems for Vector menu, but their solution is only for processing menus.

I'm on a new install of Manjaro KDE 21.0.1 and I've tried different version of Qgis. I've never experienced this kind of problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I found a solution, by deleting all folders in `~/local/share/QGIS`.
I found also that in QGIS github page they suggest to create a new profile in QGIS,

I copied the instructions from this [page](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html?highlight=profile#working-with-user-profiles)

By default, a QGIS installation contains a single user profile named `default`. But you can create as many user profiles as you want:

1. Click the New profile… entry.
2. You’ll be prompted to provide a profile name, creating a folder of the same name under `~/<UserProfiles>/`
   The user profile folder can be opened from within QGIS using the `Open Active Profile` Folder.
3. A new instance of QGIS is started, using a clean configuration. You can then set your custom configurations.